# Geometry nodes - Curve to mesh with profile and taper or scaling in two axis

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to extrude a rectangular handrail along an existing spiraling curve. The handrail should get thinner and wider at the end of the spiral (as if it was blacksmithed). Setting a curve radius only gives me control of the thickness, but I want the thinner parts to also be wider (in Y axis). In other words, the extrusion profile should gradually change from a square to a flat rectangular at the center of the spiral.
Any hints would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: do you mean like this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFcOW.png

Comment: @Chris, yes that's it

Answer (score 4):

Either use curve radius for one dimension, and for the other counter it (scale by a reciprocal $1 \over r$) and scale by the radius you want:

[image]

Or just solidify ("bevel") the edge yourself:

[image]

The two solutions aren't exactly the same, due to the last extrude not being preceded with "Set position" to maintain mean mass close to original curve, also maybe because in one case skeleton of mesh is constructed on points, and in another it's edges (curve segments) rather than points, that produce thickness, so the interpolation could slightly change the shape. Also, as you can clearly see below, I didn't put much effort to make the results similar:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4):

with this node tree:

[image]

you will get this:

[image]