# How to use float curve node to flatten geometry from two sides rather than all four sides in geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, procedural

I am trying to show this vein being compressed from only two sides so it "pancakes" and flattens out rather than compresses circularly from all sides.

[image]

As of right now I have two float curve nodes so I can have the vein oscillate between compressed and uncompressed in my animation. Here is a visualization of what is happening and what I want to happen...

[image]

Really appreciate any help or feedback! Thanks guys!

Full geometry node setup...

[image]

Comment: A duplicate? [Geometry nodes - Curve to mesh with profile and taper or scaling in two axis](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/309985/60486)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to squeeze it in one direction only, you want to do it on a part of your GN you're not showing: the curve cross-section.

[image]

Here, I'm mixing between the position of a scaled cross-section and an unscaled cross-section so that you can see how you might transition between one.  I'm also doing something dumb to the curve tilt to demonstrate how the eventual outcome of this scaling depends on the curve tilt, so that you can control exactly where the scaling occurs by controlling the tilt-- possibly, even changing that across your curve, as I'm doing.

Comment: Hey man, thank you for answering. I am extremely new to geometry nodes. this is a setup I got from Ryo Mizuta (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=whh1QblAGEo&t=1s&pp=ygUTcnlvIG1penV0YSBncmFwaGljcw%3D%3D). What you are doing is exactly what I am looking for, I just don't know how to implement it. I posted the full geo node setup to the end of my original post. Any way you could give me some guidance on how to implement what you are doing into this setup? Thanks again!

Comment: Not without having any idea of what's inside those node groups, and possibly, not even then, because it looks complicated.  Implement on something simple first, then build your way up to your full complicated structure.